# Framework installation got frozen

Tags: installation, windows-xp-sp3

I wanted to install the sp1 of microsoft framework 3.0 and at 100% it stucked. I decided let it go for a while. However, it didnt help. By the info icon is written: Downloading ended. You may disconnect from the internet.

Then hopeless i clicked on - CANCEL - as you see (storno) and it does nothing till now.
I dont want to close it manually, I want to find an easy solution.

:( I dont have enough reputation to post images so here is the link:
http://s4.postimg.org/di4afrb25/Bez_n_zvu.jpg